# How to fix the end point of the ROC graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created the ROC graph. But it is unlike the normal ones.

The usual ROC graph:

[image: The usual ROC graph]

My ROC graph:

[image: My ROC graph]

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Import the data from output file
#from output import *
from output1 import *

plt.figure('All Profile')
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC)')
plt.ylim(ymax = 1.0000, ymin = 0.0000)
plt.xlim(xmax = 1.0000, xmin = 0.0000)
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate (TPR)')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate (FPR)')
plt.grid(True)
# The diagonal line
x = [0.0, 1.0]
plt.plot(x, x, linestyle='dashed', color='red', linewidth=2, label='random')

# FPRlist and TPRlist the variable that save the data in output file
plt.plot(FPRlist, TPRlist, linewidth=2,  marker='o', color='b')
plt.show()
```

and this is my data that I save in output1.py

```
TPRlist=['0.995', '0.989', '0.972', '0.799', '0.317', '0.198', '0.071', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000']
FPRlist=['0.487', '0.475', '0.465', '0.292', '0.143', '0.085', '0.001', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000', '0.000']
```

So what should I do? Is it because of my data that I got the graph like that?

Comment: Please, can you be more specific

Comment: Please add your code so people can see what you're doing wrong and give you better support. Currently, your question requires too much puzzling for others to find out what's wrong.

Comment: By the way, if you install `seaborn` package and just write `import seaborn as sns` before your plotting code, you'll immediately get much prettier plot appearance.

Comment: I have already updated my code. Tq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input data for the ROC usually contain two very naive operating points:

1. All samples are classified as negatives, TPR=0 and FPR=0
2. All samples are classified as positives, TPR=1 and FPR=1

Comment: So I need to initial the TPR and FPR as 1 for positive?

Comment: I do not think you really "need" to plot that operating point, but you can if you want a traditional ROC, starting in (0,0) and ending in (1,1). You can also just use the graph you show, it's not necessarily wrong have the graph end in a better operating point then (1,1).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I really want to get the traditional ROC. So what should I do? Because my data did start with (0,0) but not ending with (1,1)

Comment: How did you calculate your TPR and FPR values? The best would be to generate your data in a way that it also outputs (1,1). That is, as I described in the answer, when you classify all samples as positives.

Comment: I calculate TPR = TP/(TP+TN) and FPR = FP/(FP+TN). Sorry, I do not understand what do you means by "classify all samples as positives"? because I am very new and this is the first time I creating the ROC graph.

Comment: Thank you for all people help me.. My problem have solve.:-). Now I know what means by "classify all samples as positives". I just put my threshold as 0 (the way to get the TPR and FPR) to get all the samples as positives.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that some parts of the ROC just coincide with the axes limits, you may simply write this before `plt.show()`:

```
plt.ylim(-0.005, 1.005)
plt.xlim(-0.005, 1.005)
```